# Angularjs Expression

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to display the html tags from the data in the view.I have a data `level` which is `$scope.level="<b>i should be bold</b>"` and when the data is given in the template as given below should respect the html tag as well

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
{{level}}
</div>
```

that is it should be bold without using

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="tableForVxp" class="dataDisplay2">
<b>{{level}}</b>
</div>
```

But with what i have tried so far i am not able to achive it.It is also showing the tag in the view.The issue is illustrated in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/u37xtpjd/1/) [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/u37xtpjd/1/).

Is there anyway to achieve it.or am i totally wrong here?

Comment: you will need to use the [Strict Conceptual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service (`$sce`) and use `ng-bind-html` rather than expressions `{{ }}`

Comment: also, when submitting a fiddle with an issue, it is usually helpful to ensure that the version of angular in the fiddle is up to date.  It is unlikely that you are working with angular 1.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **ngBindHtml** directive which evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element. Don't forget to include the **ngSanitize** directive.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Example :

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = '<b>my text</b>'
});
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
 <p ng-bind-html="data"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="tableForVxp" class="dataDisplay2">
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="level"></div>
</div>
```

Unsafe because the DOM should generally not be modified inside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you move the `<b>` tags to the markup and then just interpolate the value of 'level'?

http://jsfiddle.net/u37xtpjd/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="tableForVxp" class="dataDisplay2">
  <span ng-bind-html="level"></span>
</div>
```