# Use of $compile service on dynamically created objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to get `ng-click` to work on a series of dynamically created buttons I have after I:

- iterate over items in object
- find particular matches
- replacing them with html string

(refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623961/iterate-over-items-in-object-find-matches-and-replace) for more detail)

I understand that I need to make use of the $compile service to do this but I am not sure how to implement it into my code from the examples I have seen so far. Any idea how? At the moment, nothing happens...

**phrase-list.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="{{ category }}">
  <ion-content>

    <div class="list">
      <a class="item item-text-wrap item-line-height" ng-bind-html="e.phrase_filter" ng-repeat="e in phraseList = (categoryDetail | orderBy:'phrase_filter')">
      </a>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controllers.js**

```
/**
*
*/
function PhraseListCtrl($scope, $stateParams, CategoryService, ModalService) {

    $scope.categoryId = $stateParams.categoryId;
    $scope.category = $stateParams.category;

    CategoryService.getCategoryDetail($scope.categoryId).then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.categoryDetail = dataResponse.data;

        var replacers = CategoryService.getCategoryFilter();

        $scope.categoryDetail.forEach(function(e){
            Object.keys(replacers).forEach(function(key){
                e['phrase_filter'] = e['phrase_filter'].replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), replacers[key]);
            })
        })

    })

    // Modals

    var vm = $scope;

    $scope.phraseItemModal = function() {
            ModalService.show('templates/modals/phrase-item.html', 'PhraseListCtrl as vm');
        }

}
```

**services.js**

```
/**
*
*/
function CategoryService($http) {

    this.getCategoryList = function () {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dingocv.herokuapp.com/api/category/',
        });

    }


    this.getCategoryDetail = function (categoryId) {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dingocv.herokuapp.com/api/category/' + categoryId,
        });

    }

    this.getCategoryFilter = function () {

        var replacers = {
            '{{group}}' : '<a ng-click="phraseItemModal()" class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">group</a>',
            '{{attribute}}' : '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">attribute</a>',
            '{{factor}}' : '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">factor</a>',
            '{{person}}' : '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">person</a>'
        }

        return replacers;

    }

}
```

Comment: You could use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722343/angular-directives-inside-ng-bind-html-is-not-evluated) to achieve your goal

Comment: @PankajParkar is right. Good solution.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using: https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile to solve the problem.